# Why might a connection stay in TIME_WAIT for hours or even days?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tcp, time-wait

Our environment is ubuntu 12.04 on EC2.

I know TIME_WAIT is a good thing, and I know generally it's OK to see connections remain in TIME_WAIT for up to 2 minutes according to all the reading I've been doing.

However, we have instances which have many connections in TIME_WAIT that have remained in that state for over 24 hours now, with no corresponding connection on the other side.

Now, I realize that I can just restart networking or even the whole instance to close these connections, but I'm more curious about the mechanisms at play here and why these connections aren't closing themselves within the "2 * Minimum Segment Interval" that I've heard about.

Thanks!

Comment: Any changes to the `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` sysctl?